# SpyOn javascript array function in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test a JS -

```
var providers = [];
providers.push(1);
```

How do I spyOn push? I have tried the following with no success -

```
var providers = jasmine.createSpyObj('providers', ['push'])
expect(providers.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: As the other answers have suggested, you can create a spy with `spyOn(providers, 'push'). But you need providers to be available to spy on, possibly by getting a private property for the purpose of the test.

Comment: it really depends on what to you want to do. spyOn() spies on an existing object, while createSpyObj() creates a new mock object, wich is usally in jected to your tested code. can you please add some more code?

Comment: @ronapelbaum The code I have provided is sufficient. There is nothing else in the function related to this. So i basically have an array initialization and then a push to the array in that function. I want to test if the push has been called.

Comment: unfortunarly, i can't find a way tom spy on javascript primitives with jasmine.

I would try to build my code so that i'll test the result of that push.

Answer (score 1):

refer this https://daveceddia.com/jasmine-2-spy-cheat-sheet/
, so it should be

```
spyOn(providers, 'push');
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `spyOn` with the object and the method name you want to spy on:

```
spyOn(providers, 'push');
```

Make sure you call `push()` after you spy on it.

Comment: This would require me to define providers within the jasmine test correct? Also, I would expect the push() call inside the actual function and not inside the jasmine test. Am I right in assuming this?

Comment: providers has to be accessible from the test, but it doesnt have to be defined in the test. Maybe providers is a property on the object you are testing. The push call would be in the function you are testing. But if you are doing that, it sounds like private details that your test shouldn't care about. Could you provide more details about the function you are testing?